# Am i getting html and javascript code when using ajax to pass parameters to the function on onClick event (Ajaxing on the same page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<html>
    tables, textbox, buttons
</html>

<?php

//some php, sql stuff


    echo "<td><input type='button' name='disable' value='Disable' onClick='disable($id);'/></td>";

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="delete")
    { 
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
        $id = $_POST['ID'];
        echo "Id:".$id;

       //Call to another function  

      die();

    }

?>

<script>
    function disable(id) { 
        jQuery.ajax({   type: 'Post', 
                    url: '', 
                    data: {action: 'delete', ID: id} 
        })
        .done(function(data) { 
           alert("Data Saved: " + data); 
            location.reload();
        }); 
    }

</script>
```

Alert box is showing html code which is in HTML block and successful messages from php block. I don't need to show HTML code, only need to show successful messages. How to do that??? many thanks

Comment: If you see HTML, the server is returning HTML, and the issue is in the PHP code you haven't posted, but most likely you're returning the same document that you're currently on, as you haven't specified an URL

Comment: I have modified the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to respond to the ajax request *before any html is sent to the browser* and call `exit;` to stop the remaining page content from being sent as well. Something like this would work:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='delete'){
    // process request...... 
    $id = $_POST['ID'];
    echo "Id:".$id;
    //Call to another function 
    exit; // stop the script here so it doesnt also return the html content of the page
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
tables, textbox, buttons

<?php
//some php, sql stuff 
// note that $id is not defined where you try to use it here in your code, not sure what that's about....
echo "<td><input type='button' name='disable' value='Disable' onClick='disable($id);'/></td>";
?>
<script>
    function disable(id) {
        jQuery.ajax({   type: 'Post',
            url: '',
            data: {action: 'delete', ID: id}
        })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert("Data Saved: " + data);
                location.reload();
            });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am already using die(); . But I tried with exit as well and the above changes, still showing html in alert box.

Comment: @PoojaKshatriya does the ` "Id:".$id;` part get echo'd in the response at all? Or is the repsonse *just* the html of the page?

Comment: Yes it is.. My alert box shows html tags and all that at the top and passed variables and successful messages at the bottom of the alert box.

Comment: @PoojaKshatriya Note that I placed the check `if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='delete')` at the very top."*before any html is sent to the browser*". Your code has the check at the bottom of the file. This means that the page sends all of the content of your page to the browser *then it checks for the post var and sends the response*. Look closer at the structure of the code in my answer, mirror that and it will work. Also, your script tag needs to be moved to just above the closing `body` tag, it should not be outside the `html` tag as you have it now.